# Ruby, Within a While Loop, Convert String to Method Call

Tags: ruby, methods

This is lives within a method "play" that is called once. After you enter the while loop, you stay there until you exit the process. Right now, I'm trying to use the case statement to turn user-defined strings into the variable that is passed at the end to call the next method, all within the while loop.

```
def play
  next_action = @start # comes from an initialize function earlier in script
  while true
    case next_action
    when beginning
      next_action = beginning
    when "instruct"
      next_action = instructions
    when "display"
      next_action = display_users
    else
      puts "Unknown command."
      next_action = display_users
    end
    puts "\n----------"
    next_action = method(next_action).call
  end
end
```

First problem: the case statement fails to recognize any choice but the last.

Second problem: this leads to the loop ending, jumping to the last method called, and then exiting the process.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See if changing

```
next_action = @start
```

to:

```
next_action = @start.chomp
```

gets you any further.

Comment: private method `chomp' called for :beginning:Symbol (NoMethodError)

Comment: It seems that whatever `next_action` is, it is not a string, so it will probably not equal "instruct","display" etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a state-machine instead.

See: http://railscasts.com/episodes/392-a-tour-of-state-machines

Comment: This *is* a state machine. It's just not using an existing FSM gem.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that, Chris. I was getting more than a little confused as to how my code *wasn't* a state machine.